# Is this possible to add more required Fields in django rest framework (while log in)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At first i wanna say that my code is not important here. I wanna understand logick how this works. So when i try to Login with Django Rest Framework i need to pass 2 fields "Password and Username". Is this possible to add more required fields for example i need to pass email to log in. And How do i make it compare to data that i passed while registering user. (sorry for eanglish)

I wanna make this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimv3.png)

Fields only required to log in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esuy9.png)

**Images Fixed**

Comment: Both links refer to the *same* image.

Comment: Allredy fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Well, login can be anything you want. See an example here :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples

What you need to understand is own you keep your users logged. This is done through the Authentication engines, which you can implement yourself, or keep something simple like session (cookies).
But you can even do "log-less" actions by using pre-generated token, or even using headers if you're using an proxy that setup users for you, etc.

Here is another view from SimpleJWT that generate your token (which is then used with the middleware to perform authentication when your client sends it): https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/views.py